# How to build project from maven pom file

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven pom file for an open source project. This pom file has all the info like what other jars it depends on etc. I installed maven. Created a dir samprj and copied the pom file into that dir. Cd into that dir and ran mvn command without any arguments but I got bunch of errors. I am absolutely new to maven so I think I am missing something. I tried also from Eclipse ( Import project -- exisitng maven project) but that also does not work except eclipse creates a project that has just that file pom.xml. I expect something that first it will download the jar for the project and then download all dependent jars and config files but nothing there.
So given a pom file how do I build the project from it?

Comment: You should list the "bunch of errors", it will make it easier(/possible!) for people to work out what went wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to open this within Eclipse, you need to install m2eclipse:

- http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/

and then import the project as a Maven project as described here:

- http://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/creating-sect-importing-projects.html

Answer (score 35):

`mvn install` should get you going

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 10):

> I have a maven pom file for an open source project. This pom file has all the info like what other jars it depends on etc. I installed maven. Created a dir samprj and copied the pom file into that dir ...

It sounds like you only have the project's POM file.  This is not sufficient.  You need to *checkout the complete source tree* for the project.  Having done that, change directory to the directory containing the POM file and run `mvn install`.

Also, don't copy the POM to a different directory.  Maven expects to find all of the source files relative to the POM file location.

**FOLLOW UP**

> Thanks for advice. I was not able to use the command mvn install as it gave errors.

Probably because you hadn't checked out the source.

> I don't know how to check the source tree of the project ...

Use a subversion client (the `svn` command for example), or one of the Eclipse subversion plugins.

If this was a properly documented project, there would be clear instructions on what version control and build tools you needed, how to checkout the source code and how to build it.

> ... as I thought POM itself should have this information to automatically checkout if the source is not check out.

It doesn't necessarily, though in this particular case it does.

> Anyway I was able use Eclipse to build the project without errors.

(Other readers can read @icyrock.com's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4173103/139985) for links to the m2eclipse plugin and documentation.)

> The only problem is the dependent jars were downloaded but hidden deep paths in .m2 repository folder on my linux box.
>
> But I would like these dependent jars to be relative to dir where POM file is.

Sorry, but that is not the way Maven works.

The `~/.m2/repository` directory is a fundamental part of Maven.  It is not a problem.  It is a feature.  (Don't fight it!)

Answer (score 0):

Try out their getting started guide.  It has a lot of good examples:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/