# How to download with Maven a project jar and its dependencies without checking out the sources

Tags: maven

In one Java project, I have configured its POM so maven will generate in the *target* folder:

- the binaries jar.
- the sources jar.
- the javadocs jar.
- the tests jar.

In addition, I configured the POM so Maven downloads all the project dependencies in the *target/lib* folder.
The project is also uploaded to the Sonatype snapshots repository.

My question is: Is it possible for a user of my library to download all the artefacts mentioned above with one single instruction, **without having to checkout the sources of my project first** ?

I found in [a question from some years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173000/how-to-build-project-from-maven-pom-file) that just distributing the POM is not enough to download a project and its dependencies.
But I have not lost hope that this could be possible to accomplish in one single step.

Comment: Why do you care if it's one step?  Nobody else using maven cares.  I can set my IDE to do both steps every time so I never have to think about it.

Comment: I agree with the advantages of using Maven with an IDE. My question is if users can download the relevant artifacts in one single step without requiring them to use a particular IDE. Maybe they only need the binaries to run them in their local machine (without linking them with another project), or only want to take a look to the javadocs API offline, etc.

Comment: Yes but why?  If it takes 2 steps, they still get all they need.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "all of the artifacts mentioned above", do you mean:

> - the binaries jar.
> - the sources jar.
> - the javadocs jar.
> - the tests jar.

or do you mean:

> all the project dependencies

Assuming the latter, then have your user do the following:

- create a dummy pom.xml file
- declare your library as a dependency
- use [maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html) to copy jars into desired location

Hope that helps.

Comment: I mean both. I would like my users to download all the jars in the list + the project dependencies, in one single step, without checking out the sources.

Comment: I'm not sure whether my solution will handle the binaries+sources+javadocs+tests jar.  But it will definitely handle all the transitive project dependencies.